# How to eval a string val in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have scala expression stored in String variable:

```
val myExpr = "(xml \ \"node\")"
```

How do I execute this?

```
s"${myExpr}"
```

Right now it only gives me the string contents

What I'm trying to achieve is parsing user string input in the form:

```
"/some/node/in/xml"
```

and get that corresponding node in Scala:

```
(xml \ "node" \ "in" \ "xml")
```

Comment: That's generally a bad idea.

Comment: I have no clue how to get around doing so.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this in the end? I'm confident there's a better task for the job.

Comment: Made edits to my post to describe what I'm doing.  I need to execute user generated xPath expressions.

Comment: Then use a Scala XPath library.  Don't do this!

Answer (score 1):

For the REPL, my init includes:

```
implicit class interpoleter(val sc: StringContext) {def i(args: Any*) = $intp interpret sc.s(args: _*) }
```

with which

```
scala> val myExpr = "(xml \\ \"node\")"
myExpr: String = (xml \ "node")

scala> val xml = <x><node/></x>
xml: scala.xml.Elem = <x><node/></x>

scala> i"${myExpr}"
res3: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<node/>)
res2: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IR.Result = Success
```

because isn't code really just a string, like everything else?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there is some more idiomatic way in recent scala versions, but you can use [Twitter's Eval](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-eval/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Eval.scala#L48) for that:

```
val i: Int = new Eval()("1 + 1") // => 2
```

Comment: Please don't use `Eval`! We're trying to kill it!

Comment: @TravisBrown what's the reasoning behind this? Can you elaborate on this?